# Laravel HasManyThrough Returns Property [X] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many-through, laravel-8

I actually managed to get data from HasManyThrough relations, but when I want to reach the relational data, it throws the error:

```
Property [publishings] does not exist on this collection instance.
(View: C:\Xampp\htdocs\wave\resources\views\pages\category.blade.php)
```

As can be seen in the picture down below, I received "publishings" data.

[image]

Where I got the error from is this Blade file:

**category.blade.php**

```
@foreach ($data->publishings as $item)
  <div></div>
@endforeach
```

Since I have the data, the codes down below can be unnecessary for the solution, but they are there, just in case.

**CategoryController.php**

```
public function index($category)
{
   $data = Category::where('slug', $category)
      ->with(['publishings' => function ($query) {
          $query->where('slug', '!=', 'placeholder')->latest()->paginate(10);
      }])->get();
   return view('pages.category')->with('data', $data);
}
```

**Category.php**

```
public function assets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Asset');
}
public function publishings()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Publishing', 'App\Models\Asset');
}
```

**Asset.php**

```
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
}
public function publishings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Publishing');
}
```

**Publishing.php**

```
public function asset()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Asset');
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since we don't know what `<x-grid>` does, maybe try something else there that is reproducible, and an actual error message to match. Are you testing that the relationship actually exists before trying to access it?

Comment: I removed x-slot and still the same error because foreach throws the error. I added the actual error message to the question. I think the relationship exists, otherwise, I wouldn't have managed to fetch data. As you can see in the picture, I have the data with relations.

Comment: I've found the problem. So stupid mistake.

Comment: You would still fetch data even if the relationship doesn't exist. If you want to filter based on relationship, use `whereHas()`, not `with()` which is for limiting eager load.

Comment: I answered my question. The solution is embarrassingly easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing an Eloquent Collection to the view. If you want to query only the first result, you can use the `first()` method of the Query Builder instead of `get()`:

```php
public function index($category)
{
    $data = Category::where('slug', $category)
        ->with(['publishings' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('slug', '!=', 'placeholder')->latest()->paginate(10);
        }])->first();
    return view('pages.category')->with('data', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem and comes across this message, the solution, in my case was actually quite easy. The 3rd line in the picture says:

```
0 => App\Models\Category
```

And I was trying to reach the relational data as if the $data is an object. That's why

```
$data->publishings
```

thrown the error. Solution is

```
$data[0]->publishings
```

Or return only that data from the controller:

```
return view('pages.category')->with('data', $data[0]);
```